# Outline how Java Swing allows the use of multiple layouts in a single JFrame based window.

Tags: java, swing

I need help answering this question as I can't find the answer, if anyone could help I'd appreciate it, thanks.
Full question below:

Outline how Java Swing allows the use of multiple layouts in a single JFrame based window. 
When would you need to use multiple layouts? Give an example to support your answer.

Comment: *"Give an example to support your answer"* Here is a really good one: [Nested Layout Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621338/how-to-add-jtable-in-jpanel/5630271#5630271)

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't.  You can nest different JPanels inside the JFrame, each with their own layout.